# Regex to remove specific match of conditions in text (php)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need a way to remove the "U." part of the string only when "**. U.**" or "**.U.**" are at the end of the string itself (1st case is with a space and the 2nd without it).

1. Que tiene amistad.U.
2. Que tiene amistad. U.
3. Im fan of U. of Chicago.
4. Im fan of the Knicks. U. of Chicago.

From these 4 strings, it should only be applied to 1 and 2. So the resulting texts in each case would be:

1. Que tiene amistad.
2. Que tiene amistad.
3. Im fan of U. of Chicago.
4. Im fan of the Knicks. U. of Chicago.

I tried several alternatives with **str_replace()**, but this has to be done with regex because of the conditions bosted above. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the function `preg_replace()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm answering this way too often, but a ["lookbehind" assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) might work here:

```
= preg_replace("/(?<=\. |\.)U\.$/", "", $str);
```

That leaves dot and/or trailing space in, only looks at them as condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$` to anchor your regex to the end of the string.  The `\s?` looks for a possible space.

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/\s?U\.$/", "", $string);


$string = "Que tiene amistad. U.";
$new_string = preg_replace("/\s?U\.$/", "", $string);
echo $new_string;

// Que tiene amistad.

$string = "Im fan of U. of Chicago.";
$new_string = preg_replace("/\s?U\.$/", "", $string);
echo $new_string;

// Im fan of U. of Chicago.
```

Comment: That answer should be pretty comprehensive. However, as you specially requested the dot in front of the U, I would suggest changing the command to `preg_replace("/.\s?U\.$/", ".", $string)`

Comment: @Thilo If you look at the OP's desired output, the final `.` before the `U` is still present, hence not replaced by the regexp.

Comment: Yes, it is. However, your expression would also alter "This is a dummyU.". That is why I replaced the whole found string with the dot and did not remove it.

Comment: @Thilo try your regex with this string: 'Hola amigos U.' < problem

Comment: @andufo Granted. The excuse may be lame, but there was a backslash supposed to be in front of the first dot... However, my solution still does remove the space between the . and the U if it is present - as do the other solutions except of marios. +1 for that.